# Activity Indicator not getting rendered in Absolute Layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to show an Activity Indicator in my App for which I have written the following code but the indicator is not getting rendered on the screen.
Can somebody please suggest what has gone wrong?

```
private ActivityIndicator indicator = new ActivityIndicator
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    Color = Color.Black,

    IsVisible = false
};



StackLayout stack = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Padding=0,
                    Spacing=0,
                };

                AbsoluteLayout absolute = new AbsoluteLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                };


  stack.Children.Add(map);
  stack.Children.Add(browser);

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(stack, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stack, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));

AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(indicator, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(indicator, new Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize));


  absolute.Children.Add(indicator);
  absolute.Children.Add(stack);



*//When Some activity occurs.....Indicator is shown like this*

 indicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsVisibleProperty, "IsBusy", BindingMode.OneWay);
            indicator.SetBinding(ActivityIndicator.IsRunningProperty, "IsBusy", BindingMode.OneWay);
            indicator.IsRunning = true;
            indicator.IsVisible = true;
```

Comment: Try this `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stack, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));` to the `stack` and `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(indicator, new Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, -1f, -1f));` to the `indicator`. Also add `AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(stack, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);` to the stack.

Comment: No, @Akash Its still not getting rendered.

Comment: Add the indicator after the stack. `absolute.Children.Add(stack);` before `absolute.Children.Add(indicator);`

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: Whats your indicator code? This works for me.

Comment: I have edited the question, Please have a look at it.

Comment: Can you try adding `VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand`to the indicator. And just to check if it is coming or not make `IsRunning=true` and `IsVisible=true`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112226/discussion-between-abhi-and-akash-amin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(stack, new Rectangle(0f, 0f, 1f, 1f));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(indicator, new Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, -1f, -1f));
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(stack, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
```

Add the indicator after the stack. `absolute.Children.Add(indicator)` after `absolute.Children.Add(stack)`;

Check If your `IsVisible` is true.